# How to get the begin and end of an array that was created by new

Tags: c++

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
int* b = new int[3]{4,5,6};
```

I want to get the begin and end of b. `std::begin()`works in `a`but not in `b`. Is there an suitable way to get the two positions of `b`?

Comment: I discourage you to use naked new. Use `array` or `vector` instead.

Comment: You have no recourse but to keep track of the buffer size (that 3 there). Better to write a class that does that. Hey, have you heard about `std::vector`?

Comment: If you insist on using regular arrays, you have to either keep track of the number of elements or do something similar to a null terminated string, where you use some value that will never occur in your normal data to mark the end of the array, then iterate through the array until you reach this special value.

Comment: You can't use the `std::begin()` function on `int*` pointer. You need to roll your own solution or utilize the `std::unique_ptr` as it accepts the `T[]` array type. As a side-note the`int[] a` should be `int a[]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you see a reference to [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) you will see that beginning and end iterators are in way pointers to the first and one-beyond-last elements of the container. For arrays this is doubly-true because then you can use actual pointers for the iterators.

For an array like `a` the `std::begin` function returns a *pointer to the first element*, and the `std::end` function returns a *pointer to one beyond the last element*.

Now when you know that information it's easy to figure out what "begin" and "end" iterators for a pointer is, because it's exactly the same as for an array. I.e. pointers to the first and one-beyond-last elements.

In the case of your example, the "begin iterator" is simply `b` (because it points to the first element), and the "end iterator" is `b + 3` which is a pointer to one beyond the last element.

Comment: Uh, isn't that just for the std::array wrapper, not actual c style arrays?

Comment: @Matt [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) iterators are random-access iterators, and can be implemented using plain pointers, but they don't have to. For a plain C-style array the implementation is most likely pointers since it's the simplest.

Comment: You can't use `std::begin` on a pointer. There's an overload for an array reference which knows its size, but this does not hold for plain pointers.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I never said that you could use `std::begin` and `std::end` for pointers. I say that for an array (like `a` in the question) then they *return* pointers.